# python : groupby a column of user objects in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe 
`df = pd.DataFrame({"route": [route0, route0, route1, route1], "period": [0,1,0,1], "value": [1,0,2,0]}`\

```
df
Out[17]: 
    route  period  value
0  route0       0      1
1  route0       1      0
2  route1       0      2
3  route1       1      0
```

where route0, route1 are instances of a class named "Route" that I defined. 
when I try to groupby the route, ie `df.groupby("route")` I get the following message:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'Route' and 'Route'.
```

how can I group by the column "route" ?

Comment: You need to either implement `<` for `Route` or try to pass `sort=False` to groupby.

Comment: it seems you need to implement `__lt__` method or method suggested by Quang Hoang

Comment: Please give a fully working example. In your code snippet you have not declared `route0`, etc. From the error message it seems that they are of a class 'Route' that does not have a `__lt__` operator defined for it.

Comment: @QuangHoang Indeed adding `sort=False` do the trick. Thanks! maybe you can add it as an answer. thanks for your help !

Comment: @DovGrobgeld yes correct class Route does not have a `__lt__ `operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @QuangHoang, adding `sort = False` to groupby solves the issue easily.

Adding `__lt__` to the class `Route` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to add a name attribute to your class **init** and use route.name to construct and group your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
class Route:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

route0 = Route("route0")
route1 = Route("route1")

df = pd.DataFrame({"route": [route0.name,route0.name,route1.name,route1.name],
                   "period": [0,1,0,1],
                   "value": [1,0,2,0]})

grouped = df.groupby("route")
for idx, group in grouped:
    print(group)
```

Output:

```
    route  period  value
0  route0       0      1
1  route0       1      0
    route  period  value
2  route1       0      2
3  route1       1      0
```